# Is it possible to create an instance of an object in Java without calling the constructor?

Tags: java

I'm trying to fix a bug in one of my programs which I think might be due to Hibernate figuring out how to instantiate an instance of an object without calling its default (or any other) constructor.

Comment: You should possibly post the original problem rather than a supposed solution.

Comment: Hibernate uses the default empty constructor of entities. You're on the wrong track. Post your problem instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Actually, yes, it is possible to bypass the constructor when you instantiate an object, if you use [objenesis](http://code.google.com/p/objenesis/) to instantiate the object for you. It does bytecode manipulations to achieve this.

Deserializing an object will also bypass the constructor.

It isn't possible to do this using reflection.

Answer (score 10):

Just to complete the picture: using method `clone` to create a new object bypasses constructors as well.

Comment: Provided that clone() is correctly implemented, of course. It is possible to override clone to act as a factory method not using super.clone(). (While super.clone() should be used - not the constructor)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, deserializing an object does not invoke its constructor.

That said, I don't see why hibernate would serialize an object, unless perhaps in the second level cache.

Answer (score 7):

Deserialization involves creating objects without invoking a constructor.

It's possible (at least with the Sun/Oracle JDK) to do this programmatically. This was covered in ["Creating Objects Without Calling Constructors"](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue175.html), an edition of [The Java Specialists' Newsletter.](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/archive.jsp) It involves using classes from the `sun.*` packages so isn't portable.