# How to run the method from final class with private constructor?

Tags: java

How to run the method foo() in class A without any changes on this class

```
public final class A{

    private A(){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public void foo(){

        System.out.println("from foo");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why does your constructor close the whole system?  I'm legitimately curious.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Ha! I hadn't even looked at the body of the constructor. Yeah, this looks like either an intentionally weird puzzle, or some seriously bad coding. Side effects in constructors are generally not so great, and you can't have a much bigger side effect that shutting down the JVM...

Comment: I am curious to know what type of advantage we can get like a class of this type?

Answer (score 1):

Without doing something like using reflection or bytecode manipulation to mess with accessibility...

The "right" way to do this is to get an instance of the class some other way. For example, if there's a static factory method or pre-made instances that you can access. The reason for having a private constructor like this is to control construction of the class. (For example, enum implementations have a private constructor so that you don't create additional instances beyond the static ones supplied.)

If you side-step this then *someone* (either you or the original class author) is doing something wrong.

Comment: How can we get pre-made instance when default constructor is private?

Comment: @thinksteep Something in the class would have to call the constructor for you, like a static factory method, a static initializer, or something in a nested/containing class (this actually goes through a static method under the covers). If so such thing exists then your class is uninstantiable without "tricks", so I'd argue that it's probably broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of a class without calling the constructor.  See this question: [Is it possible to create an instance of an object in Java without calling the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488097/is-it-possible-to-create-an-instance-of-an-object-in-java-without-calling-the-co)

You can use [objenesis](http://code.google.com/p/objenesis/) to do this for you.  Once you've got an instance of `A` without calling the constructor, calling `foo` is easy.

Comment: If the class made its constructor private, it's almost certainly for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the byte code before it is loaded by the jvm. Here's a place to start:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0916/index.html