# Creating instance of object without calling superclass constructor

Tags: java, reflection, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Yes, my title sounds like I'm insane, but bear with me.

I'm trying to log everything a Minecraft Forge mod sends via its `SimpleNetworkWrapper` instance. To do this, I'm wrapping the instance in a dummy class and inserting the dummy instance into the mod via reflection.
Dummy class:

```java
package net.benjaminurquhart.decimated;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.network.simpleimpl.IMessage;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.network.simpleimpl.SimpleNetworkWrapper;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayerMP;
import net.minecraft.network.Packet;

public class FakeNetworkWrapper extends SimpleNetworkWrapper {

    private SimpleNetworkWrapper real;

    public FakeNetworkWrapper() {
        super("ctx");
    }

    protected void setChannel(SimpleNetworkWrapper channel) {
        this.real = channel;
    }
    @Override
    public Packet getPacketFrom(IMessage message) {
        return real.getPacketFrom(message);
    }
    @Override
    public void sendToAll(IMessage message) {
        real.sendToAll(message);
    }
    @Override
    public void sendTo(IMessage message, EntityPlayerMP player) {
        real.sendTo(message, player);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendToServer(IMessage message) {
        // Intercept messages here, do logging stuff
        real.sendToServer(message);
    }
}
```

The problem is, the superclass constructor creates a new packet channel with the given name (in this case, `ctx`). This breaks the real channel, since I'm creating a new channel with the same name. I can't omit the super call since there's no default constructor, and I prefer not to make a new unused channel with a different name.

Currently, I'm getting around the constructor by using `Unsafe`:

```java
Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
unsafe = (Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);

FakeNetworkWrapper wrapper = (FakeNetworkWrapper) unsafe.allocateInstance(FakeNetworkWrapper.class);
wrapper.setChannel(mod.getPacketChannel());
```

Obviously, I'd like to not use internal classes.

A quick google search shows that I can use serialization or `ReflectionFactory` instead of `Unsafe`. `ReflectionFactory` is also an internal class and serialization seems overkill. I'd also like to not include dependencies not provided by Forge (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3488120/10433739) suggests).

Is there a way to somehow bypass a call to the superclass constructor without using internal methods or serialization? Again, I understand *this is something I shouldn't be doing*, but I don't see another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should stay with Unsafe, it's kinda "unsupported" api rather than internal. (it got own module in java 9+ to separate in from pure internal one)

But first let me tell you that any way of creating class instance without calling its super constructor is something you should not do, so no matter what solution you will choose, it will never be clean. And that's why I just suggest sticking with unsafe anyway.
Also remember that constructor is not only code inside the constructor but also code initializing fields and code blocks:

```
private int something = 5;
{ somethingElse = new X(); }
```

So `something` will be 0, and `somethingElse` will be null without calling the constructor.

But there are alternatives - first 2 ones are clean but only possible under few conditions:

1. if only you use this class, then just create wrapper that does not extend original call and use it everywhere in your code base.
2. Maybe you don't need to extend SimpleNetworkWrapper directly? but extend/implement something that SimpleNetworkWrapper is implementing?
3. You can use libraries like ASM to generate class at runtime that would create instance of object without calling its constructor, as in bytecode creation of object and constructor call is a separate thing. Sadly this option requires `-noverify` jvm flag for java 7+
   And all you need to do is generate a class with a method that creates and return new instance of FakeNetworkWrapper but without calling constructor.

   ```
   mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "my/package/FakeNetworkWrapper"); // creates new instance
   mv.visitInsn(ARETURN);
   ```

   You can also generate extending class using ASM - and then change constructor so it will call Object super constructor instead of actual super class - this does not require `-noverify`
4. Keep using unsafe.
5. Use ReflectionFactory but I don't really see reason to do this.
6. Use instrumentation to modify SimpleNetworkWrapper at startup/on demand and add code to every method you want to track, or just change it's constructor so it is safe to call twice. But this also require startup flags or even more hacks to do this at runtime and will not work on pure JRE - JDK is required to do this at runtime.
7. If you can execute some code before SimpleNetworkWrapper class is even loaded, you can create own version of it and just load it first in the same class loader as original one - also might require hacks to inject it into right class loader if it is different than your one.

Comment: To address points 1 and 2, the field (I have no control over this) is declared as `private final SimpleNetworkWrapper packetChannel;`, which means I have to subclass `SimpleNetworkWrapper`. 3: I can't guarantee a `-noverify` flag at runtime. 5: same. 6: I've attempted to use instrumentation (via ByteBuddy) in the past for something else in this project. It turns out ForgeGradle doesn't shade dependencies correctly even with shadowjar. 7: Might work, but I'm not sure when that class is loaded, it could be before `preInit`. Anyways, thanks for the answer

Comment: I just checked with JDK 11; an extending class bypassing the actual superclass’ constructor by calling Object’s constructor instead, requires `-noverify`, just like omitting the constructor call. Which doesn’t make me sad…

Comment: @Holger using unsafe or reflection factory is best option anyway, I only showed other options to show that there looking for other solution will only add more pain