# How can a volatile field be unique to each thread when the constructor is only called once?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-flink

I was doing some tests with [Flink](https://flink.apache.org/) framework and stumbled upon a behavior that seemed very strange at first.

In my code, I used a custom `PngOutputFormat` class that had a

> private volatile AtomicInteger numFile;

field.
Now, when the whole program was run, the `PngOutputFormat` constructor was called only once.
Yet a method where the field was used as follows

> int numImage = numFile.incrementAndGet();

later output the same `numImage` value 12 (the amount of parallel tasks) or less times.

I have to declare the `numFile` field `static` on top of that to ensure that a different `numImage` value is output each time.
But from my prior understanding, `volatile` (and atomic) was enough to share the variable between threads and synchronize the access.

I've been thinking about it and looking for answers for a while and have since come up with one seemingly reasonable explanation:

1. A `PngOutputFormat` is instantiated in a non-parallel environment.
2. Mutliple threads are created. Each copies the `PngOutputFormat` object [through deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3488120/4584464), therefore not invoking the constructor again.
3. Each object then has a unique set of class fields and threads work completely independently.
4. Only `static` identifier ensures that threads use a reference to the same field object.

Am I correct in my assertion? Otherwise how does it work? And is the aforedescribed scenario even possible?

(I've tried using `System.identityHashCode(obj)` and apparently passing `this` (PngOutputFormat) indeed returns different object IDs. Passing the static `numFile` returns the same one and passing the non-static `numFile` returns 12 different IDs (yet when it throws an exception, the `close` method is called 24 times - twice as much ... maybe the objects are recreated in an attempt to resolve the exception?). But I'll still ask this answer to make sure, hope you don't mind. Here's the [class code](https://github.com/h4nek/flink-examples-mnist/blob/master/src/main/java/PngOutputFormat.java) for anyone interested :

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.io.RichOutputFormat;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * A more generic output format for outputing each element into a separate PNG file.
 * The type of elements is generic even though we'll only use it on byte[] images.
 * @param <T>
 */
public class PngOutputFormat<T> extends RichOutputFormat<T> {

    private final String directoryPath;
    private final String suffix;
    private static volatile AtomicInteger numFile;
    private final int numCols;
    private final int numRows;

    private BufferedImage image;
    private WritableRaster raster;

    public PngOutputFormat(String directoryPath, String suffix, int numCols, int numRows) {
        this.directoryPath = directoryPath;
        this.suffix = suffix;
        this.numCols = numCols;
        this.numRows = numRows;
        numFile = new AtomicInteger();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Configuration parameters) {
        // for now, we pass the parameters through the constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void open(int taskNumber, int numTasks) throws IOException {
        image = new BufferedImage(numCols, numRows, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        raster = image.getRaster();

        new File(directoryPath).mkdirs();  // make any directories that don't exist
    }

    @Override
    public void writeRecord(T record) throws IOException {
        int numImage = numFile.incrementAndGet();
        String filePath = directoryPath + numImage + '_' + suffix + ".png";

        raster.setDataElements(0, 0, numCols, numRows, record);
        image.setData(raster);

        File outputFile = new File(filePath);

        ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputFile);
        System.out.println("Image nr. " + numImage + " written!");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // The ImageIO closes the stream after each write, so we don't need to close anything.
    }
}
```

It only happens when running Filter programs like [this one](https://github.com/h4nek/flink-examples-mnist/blob/master/src/main/java/FilterZeroes.java), but I guess that's because Flink decides to process only these in parallel and others sequentially.)

Comment: you should post the code here. I added the class but you should add any code here that helps to understand the issue.

Comment: Volatile is not for unique ness, volatile just gurantee that, the variable will be read from the main memory. The value of volatile variable will not be cached in register.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you've copied the original object by serializing/deserializing it, you now have multiple `volatile numFile` fields (one per instance of the class). If you want to use a global incrementing counter, which is reset when the program restarts, a `private static final AtomicLong` would be the idiomatic way to do it.

Note that making an `Atomic*` "variable" `volatile` only means that the *reference* to that object is made `volatile`, which in your case seems like it would have no effect.

In general, `volatile` should only be used for optimising memory layout if an `Atomic*` instance is too expensive, IMHO.

Comment: So `Atomic` variables already have the "volatile" properties, right? And `final` is just for safety purposes?

The thing is that Flink handles the thread creation and everything, so the deserialization copy is just my guess since it apparently uses serialization quite extensively. But anyway just knowing that it's possible this way is probably enough for me.

Comment: The `Atomic*` classes provide concurrency safe primitives, so you can for example do `AtomicInteger::incrementAndGet`, which will be guaranteed to increment the counter by exactly 1, regardless of interleaving with other threads. `volatile` only guarantees that if you write something to memory before you write to the `volatile` field, other threads cannot read old values of the other memory writes. Think of `volatile` as Java's implementation of Memory Barriers. `volatile` doesn't give you a way to do `incrementAndGet` for example.