# Registering all classes that inherit from a particular abstract class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, singleton

I have a singleton object called registry.

I also have an abstract base class, say Operation with an abstract field called `name`. I expect other people to subclass this abstract class and create classes denoting specific operations. I want to be able to store `name -> Subclass` mapping in my registry object.

Ideally, people who subclass this will not even know about this registration. But if that is unavoidable, I prefer them to write as little code as possible just next to their class declaration.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: I would use a companion object with a MutableSet<Operation>. With: _init { @Suppress("LeakingThis") operations.add(this) }_ you can register classes in the Set. But I think you should elaborate what you want to achieve. What will do with the registered classes?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is `name` being abstract.

If `name` were a constructor parameter, then you could simply put the code in the your abstract class's constructor. Every subclass, sub-subclass,… instance will call that constructor (directly or indirectly), so it would always get called. (That doesn't apply to a few [special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488097/is-it-possible-to-create-an-instance-of-an-object-in-java-without-calling-the-co/3488120) such as deserialisation and cloning, so you might have to handle those explicitly.)

However, your abstract class's constructor will get called *before* the sub(sub…)class constructor(s), and so the instance won't be fully initialised and its `name` property might not be available yet.

The options I see are:

1. Refactor your class so that the name is a constructor parameter (and can't be changed thereafter), and add your code to the constructor. (If that restriction is feasible, then this is the simplest solution, both for you and for implementers of subclasses, who won't need to do anything extra.)
2. Provide a method that subclasses can call once the name has been set up. (You'll have to make it clear in the documentation that subclasses *must* call that method; unfortunately, I don't know of any way to enforce it.)
3. It may be possible to use annotations and compiler plug-ins and/or runtime libraries, similar to frameworks such as Spring. But I don't know the details, and that's likely to take *much* more work; it may also need your implementers to add plug-ins and/or libraries to their project, so probably isn't worth it unless you're doing a lot of other frameworky stuff too.

In each case, you can get the `name` value and the concrete subclass (using `this::class` or `this::class.java`), and store them in your registry. (It doesn't look like you're asking about the internals of the registry; I assume you have that side of things covered.)